# How do I solve (∂/∂x+∂/∂y+∂/∂z)^2 of u

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm trying to solve a question in which it is given that u=f(x,y,z) and it is asked to find (∂/∂x+∂/∂y+∂/∂z)^2 of u .
How do I solve this? Should I apply the formula (a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca  ? Or any other easy method ?

Comment: Is there more information? Because right now it sounds like Laplace or Poisson equation depending on the conditions

Comment: Dex, well the actual question is
If u=log(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz),show that 
(∂/∂x+∂/∂y+∂/∂z)^2 of u = (-9)/(x+y+z)^2 .

Comment: Oh so the question is to take partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes Dex. Anyway thanks, it has been answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely a suggestion on how to book keep your calculation. I will leave the actual calculations to you.

I suggest that you do it in two steps. First, calculate
$$
h=\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Bigr)u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}.
$$
(Note, that you by symmetry only need to do one of the differentiations.) After simplification, I get
$$
h=\frac{3}{x+y+z}.
$$
Then, calculate
$$
\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Bigr)^2u=\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Bigr)h=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}.
$$
When I do the calculation, I get the result
$$
-\frac{9}{(x+y+z)^2}.
$$